# Open ID Connect : what's the simplest way to do auth code flow from a (server-backed) native windows app?

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm considering how take a fairly complex application with multiple clients (some web-based, some desktop - all of which talk to an application server by .net remoting) and migrate it to use OIDC authentication with auth code flow.

One of the challenges is the desktop clients, and how to pop up a browser window to facilitate the login process, and retrieve the auth code (which can then be passed from the desktop client to the server and verified/swapped for an ID token using the back-channel - let's assume I can do that bit securely.)

https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect states:

> Embedded web views are not be trusted, as there’s nothing to prevent the app from snooping on the user password.  User authentication must always occur in a trusted context that is separate from the app (e.g. the browser).

(this is talking about mobile apps, but I assume the same applies to any native apps.)

Would the recommended way to allow an auth code flow with a windows desktop client (of a separate server application) be to launch a browser pop-up? If so, what is the recommended way to do this - would it be to embed a web server in the windows desktop app, and have the OpenID Provider use a `redirect_uri` of localhost (i.e. redirecting the browser back to the server embedded in the native windows app?)

I couldn't see any examples/samples in the set of current Identity Server 4 repos on [GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/) that were particularly similar to what I'm trying to do, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: This video might be helpful - https://vimeo.com/171942749

Answer (score 2):

The library at https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2 (Maintained by [Dominick Baier](https://github.com/leastprivilege) of Identity Server fame) seems to be the most obvious solution. It does indeed work by redirecting back to localhost - e.g. the winforms sample at https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples will give use 
`redirect_uri=http://localhost/winforms.client&response_mode=form_post`